# Are Azure AD group memberships cached locally on the user's system?

Tags: azure-active-directory

When a system is AD joined, the group memberships of the system and domain users are cached by Group Policy in the registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy..... This makes it nice to be able to query the domain group memberships of the system and its users when there isn't a connection available back to a DC.

With Azure AD, we appear to be required to provide credentials to connect to Azure and then query for group memberships. I run a process locally on my systems and don't want to pass credentials down to the system to run these queries.

I'm wondering if Azure AD group memberships are somehow cached locally on the system so I can check memberships without having to log into Azure AD first.
I'm thinking I'm out of luck here, but thought I'd ask anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD group membership are not cached locally on the user system. You need to connect to Azure AD by providing the credentials in order to query the information.

Comment: Thanks @thirgiftthub Is there any means to connect to Azure AD as local system to query the system object only and it's groups, or do all connections require credentials?

Comment: All the connections required credentials.